# Combine number and string gives 'int' object has no attribute

Tags: python

I get an 'int' object has no attribute 'format' error when I run this code
The reason being is the password has numbers and letters.

```
import subprocess

password = input('Enter New Password: ')
c = subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "Set-ADAccountPassword john -NewPassword {0} –Reset"])
f = c.format(password)

print(f)
```

I've tried

```
f = c.format(int(password))
```

and

```
f = c.format(str(password))
```

Is there a way I can specify that password contains both letters and numbers?

Comment: Please read the [description of `subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api) again, which type do you expect `c` to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying `format` to the wrong piece of code. You are applying `format` to the returned value of [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, **then return the returncode attribute.**

`returncode` is an `int`, which is why you are getting that error

Based on your commands, you need to apply `format` to the 2nd argument that is being passed into `call`

```
import subprocess

password = input('Enter New Password: ')
c1 = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
c2 = "Set-ADAccountPassword john -NewPassword {0} –Reset".format(password)

subprocess.call([c1, c2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the order all messed up,

```
password = raw_input('Enter New Password: ')

cmd1, cmd2 = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "Set-ADAccountPassword john -NewPassword {0} –Reset"

c = subprocess.call([cmd1, cmd2.format(password)])
```